# Adding data source in jdbc

Tags: jdbc

I am trying to connect to remote sql server 2008 .For that i am trying to add a data source through control panel .Admin tools->odbc server ,but i am not able to connect to the server .everytime it says connection failed .

Please tell me what can i do.

```
<%@ 
page import="java.sql.*"
%>
<%
String connectionURL = "jdbc:sqlserver://172.16.206.22,1433/mydatabase;
Connection connection = null;
Statement statement = null;
ResultSet rs = null;
%>

<html><body>

<%
Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver").newInstance();
connection = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionURL);
statement = connection.createStatement();
rs = statement.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM mytable");
while (rs.next()) 
{
out.println(rs.getString("myfield")+"<br>");
}
rs.close();
%>

</body></html>
```

Comment: Why do you think that an ODBC datasource has anything to do with JDBC?

Comment: Now what do i write in connection string ..how do i connect to remote sql server.

Answer (score 0):

The way your connecting looks incorrect - and I don't see why you need to work with ODBC here. Assuming you have the Microsoft SQL Server JDBC [drivers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/sqlserver/aa937724.aspx) then surely it's just a case of:

```
Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");
String connectionUrl = "jdbc:sqlserver://172.16.206.22;database=mydatabase;integratedSecurity=true;"
Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionUrl);
```

I'm assuming your using integrated security.

Full documentation is on MSDN - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms378672(v=sql.105).aspx.

Comment: It is showing driver is not loaded....but i have put my Microsoft jdbc driver 4.0 in C drive.and also added it to my classpath environment variable .for previous "sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver"it was showing driver loaded.

Comment: @user1896796 Applications almost never use the classpath environment variable, but have their own private classpath (eg set in the startup script).

Comment: I would read through and understand the documentation in the link above and make sure you have the full installation and set-up process covered.